# Blazor working in Release in Visual Studio - but not after publish

Tags: iis, blazor-server-side, visual-studio-2022

I have received a project, that has been developed in VisualStudio (Blazor Server and .NET 5.0).
My plan is to host this project (website with local db) on IIS, but so far I have been quite unsuccessful.

The project runs perfectly inside VisualStudio in Release but when I publish it to a localhost folder I get an error 500 (no error in VS when building/publishing).

I have installed the required NetCore Modules and Hosting bundles and I have also installed URL ReWrite.

Full permission has been granted to the user "Everyone" in the folder.

.NET CLR Version is set to "No Managed Code".

Is there anything more that I have to check? The last time I worked with localhost and IIS there was nothing called Blazor, so I am fairly rusty.

BR JD

Comment: You can refer to this link about [how to deploy a blazor application on iis](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-a-blazor-application-on-iis).

Comment: Are there any error codes in the browser dev console (when you hit F12)? 
Where is the IIS server to which you are publishing? Can you read the logs it prints to see the specific 500 error message?

Comment: @samwu I have tried to follow that guide. But I am not really sure, that my connectionstring is correct. I have tried some possible solutions from Google, but so far no luck.

Comment: @Jason the IIS Server is currently on my own Laptop, but the plan is to run it on an on-premise server.  

My IIS Log shows the following for Error 500: 
Date: 2022-01-22 21:49:03
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2022-01-22 21:49:03 ::1 GET / - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/97.0.4692.99+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 12614

And Chrome only shows 4 x Error 404 Failed to load ressource.

Janus

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.